# Function defined over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given as

$$f(x,y)= (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$$

1) Show that the determinant det D$f$ of the derivative of f is never zero.

$\frac{\partial(e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)}{\partial(x,y)}=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\\ \frac{\partial e^x\cos y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial e^x\cos y}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial e^x\sin y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial e^x\sin y}{\partial y} \end{array} \right|= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\\ e^x\cos y & -e^x \sin y \\
e^x\sin y & e^x\cos y \end{array} \right|= e^{2x}\cos^2y+e^{2x}\sin^2 y=e^{2x}>0 $

Therefore: the determinant of the derivative of f is never zero.

2) Show that f is not injective

Thank you

Comment: $\sin(y+2\pi) = \sin(y), \cos(y+2\pi) = \cos(y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you gave the answer to 1). As for 2), simply use the fact that the sine and cosine functions are periodic with period $2\pi $. Thus, $f(x,y)=f(x,y+2\pi k)$ holds for all $k\in \mathbb Z$, so obviously $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question.
We just saw what is the inverse function theorem, but I was trying to understand it through this example. What does the inverse function theorem imply about f? I mean, how does it compare to the fact the f is not injective

Comment: The inverse function theorem states that if $f$ has non-zero Jacobian (i.e., the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives) at a point $p$, then $f$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $p$. Thus, this $f$ you have here is locally invertible at every point, but it fails to be globally invertible.

Comment: So what is the connection with the non injectivity?

Comment: It just immediately shows that function is not invertible.